# VkApi. JSONException

Tags: android, vk, jsonexception

I want to display my friend's list.I don't understand why String cannot converted to json. I understand that error in 152(MainActivity)

```
JSONObject o = new JSONObject(response.toString());
```

but i don't know why...

```
JSONException: Value com.vk.sdk.api.VKResponse@42b49418 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

In logs this response show Response:

```
 {
    "response": {
        "count": 40,
        "items": [{
                    "id": 10543136,
                    "first_name": "Филип",
                    "last_name": "Канна",
                    "sex": 2,
                    "city": {
                        "id": 1710959,
                        "title": "Кишинев"
                    },
                    "online": 0
                }, ........
```

How JSON looks like VK server

```
response: {
    count: 693,
    items: [{
        id: 1987761,
        first_name: 'Александром',
        last_name: 'Мирмильштейном',
        sex: 2,
        city: {
            id: 60,
            title: 'Казань'
        },
        online: 0
    }, {
        id: 153796,
        first_name: 'Александром',
        last_name: 'Москалюком',
        sex: 2,
        city: {
            id: 1568,
            title: 'Черновцы'
        },
        online: 0
    }, {
        id: 10741,
        first_name: 'Александром',
        last_name: 'Мынзой',
        sex: 2,
        city: {
            id: 1,
            title: 'Москва'
        },
        online: 0
    }]
 }
```

My MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView text;
getFriendTask task;
ListView listView1;
VKAccessToken token;


ArrayList<Friend> friendArrayList;
ArrayAdapter<Friend> adapter;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    VKUIHelper.onCreate(this);
    VKSdk.initialize(listener, "4571964");
    VKSdk.authorize(new String[]{"friends"});



    text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
}



public void FriendClick(View view) {

     friendArrayList=new ArrayList<Friend>();
               task=new getFriendTask();
                task.execute();
                listView1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
                adapter=new FriendAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.friendlist, friendArrayList);
                listView1.setAdapter(adapter);



}

class getFriendTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        if(listener!=null) {
            VKRequest request = new VKRequest("friends.get", VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.FIELDS, "first_name, last_name, sex, bdate, city"));
            request.start();

            request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                                                super.onComplete(response);
                                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response.responseString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            try{

                    JSONObject o = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                    JSONArray jsonArray = o.getJSONArray("response");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Friend fr = new Friend();

                        fr.setFirst_name(jsonObject.getString("first_name"));
                        fr.setLast_name(jsonObject.getString("last_name"));
                        fr.setSex(jsonObject.getString("sex"));
                        fr.setBdate(jsonObject.getString("bdate"));
                        fr.setCity(jsonObject.getString("city"));

                        friendArrayList.add(fr);



                }

            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                Log.i("Are You Ready???", "Response - "+response.responseString);

                                            }

                @Override
                public void onError(VKError error) {
                    super.onError(error);
                    Log.i("Are You Ready to Fly???", "EEEror - "+error.errorMessage);

                }

                @Override
                public void attemptFailed(VKRequest request, int attemptNumber, int totalAttempts) {
                    super.attemptFailed(request, attemptNumber, totalAttempts);

                }
            });
        }
        return null;
    }


}






VKSdkListener listener=new VKSdkListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCaptchaError(VKError vkError) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onTokenExpired(VKAccessToken vkAccessToken) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccessDenied(VKError vkError) {
        Log.d("Gooooo", " My error - "+vkError.errorMessage);
    }
    public void onReceiveNewToken(VKAccessToken newToken){

        Log.d("Gooooo", "My token - "+newToken.accessToken);

        token=newToken;

    }

};

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    VKUIHelper.onResume(this);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    VKUIHelper.onDestroy(this);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    VKUIHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

public void onAutoClick(View view) {
}}
```

My Model Friend

```
  class Friend{

    String first_name;
    String last_name;
    String sex;
    String bdate;
    String city;         
        public Friend(){}
      public Friend(String first_name, String last_name, String sex, String bdate, String city){
    super();
    this.first_name=first_name;
    this.last_name=last_name;
    this.sex=sex;
    this.bdate=bdate;
    this.city=city;
    }

     public String getFirst_name(){
    return first_name;
    }
     public void setFirst_name(String first_name){
    this.first_name=first_name;
    }
     public String getLast_name(){
    return last_name;
    }
     public void setLast_name(String last_name){
    this.last_name=last_name;
    }
     public String getSex(){
    return sex;
    }
     public void setSex(String sex){
    this.sex=sex;
    }
     public String getBdate(){
    return bdate;
    }
     public void setBdate(String bdate){
    this.bdate=bdate;
    }
     public String getCity(){
    return city;
    }
     public void setCity(String city){
    this.city=city;
    }
    }
```

My FriendAdapter

```
      public class FriendAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Friend> {
 ArrayList<Friend> friendArrayList;
LayoutInflater inflater;
int Resource;
ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

public FriendAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Friend> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    Resource=resource;
    friendArrayList=objects;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View view=convertView;

    if(view==null){
    holder=new ViewHolder();
        view=inflater.inflate(Resource, null);
        holder.name=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.fname);
        holder.laname=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lname);
        holder.s=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.sx);
        holder.b=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.bd);
        holder.c=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.ct);
        view.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder=(ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    holder.name.setText(friendArrayList.get(position).getFirst_name());
    holder.laname.setText(friendArrayList.get(position).getLast_name());
    holder.s.setText(friendArrayList.get(position).getSex());
    holder.b.setText(friendArrayList.get(position).getBdate());
    holder.c.setText(friendArrayList.get(position).getCity());
    return view;
}
static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView name;
    public TextView laname;
    public TextView s;
    public TextView b;
    public TextView c;
} }
```

Error

```
10-25 22:57:33.130  31812-31812/standandroid.ru.vktestapi W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: Value com.vk.sdk.api.VKResponse@42b40ac0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
10-25 22:57:33.130  31812-31812/standandroid.ru.vktestapi W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
10-25 22:57:33.130  31812-31812/standandroid.ru.vktestapi W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
10-25 22:57:33.130  31812-31812/standandroid.ru.vktestapi W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
10-25 22:57:33.140  31812-31812/standandroid.ru.vktestapi W/System.err﹕ at standandroid.ru.vktestapi.MainActivity$getFriendTask$1.onComplete(MainActivity.java:152)
10-25 22:57:33.140  31812-31812/standandroid.ru.vktestapi W/System.err﹕ at com.vk.sdk.api.VKRequest$3.run(VKRequest.java:459)
10-25 22:57:33.150  31812-31812/standandroid.ru.vktestapi W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
10-25 22:57:33.150  31812-31812/standandroid.ru.vktestapi W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-25 22:57:33.150  31812-31812/standandroid.ru.vktestapi W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-25 22:57:33.150  31812-31812/standandroid.ru.vktestapi W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5137)
10-25 22:57:33.150  31812-31812/standandroid.ru.vktestapi W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-25 22:57:33.150  31812-31812/standandroid.ru.vktestapi W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-25 22:57:33.150  31812-31812/standandroid.ru.vktestapi W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:756)
10-25 22:57:33.150  31812-31812/standandroid.ru.vktestapi W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:572)
10-25 22:57:33.150  31812-31812/standandroid.ru.vktestapi W/System.err﹕ at miui.dexspy.DexspyInstaller.main(DexspyInstaller.java:171)
10-25 22:57:33.160  31812-31812/standandroid.ru.vktestapi W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-25 22:57:33.160  31812-31812/standandroid.ru.vktestapi I/Are You Ready???﹕ Response - {"response":{"count":40,"items":[{"id":10543136,"first_name":"Филип","last_name":"Канна","sex":2,"city":{"id":1710959,"title":"Кишинев"},"online":0},{"id":12567913,"first_name":"Юлия","last_name":"Мурашева","sex":1,"bdate":"4.4","city":{"id":1710959,"title":"Кишинев"},"online":1},{"id":15349233,"first_name":"Алёна","last_name":"Волкова","sex":1,"bdate":"31.3","city":{"id":1710959,"title":"Кишинев"},"online":1},{"id":15890365,"first_name":"Алиса","last_name":"Голдур","sex":1,"bdate":"25.2","city":{"id":1710959,"title":"Кишинев"},"online":0},{"id":17445476,"first_name":"Лена","last_name":"Стурза","sex":1,"bdate":"6.3.1995","online":1},{"id":20855237,"first_name":"Никита","last_name":"Чукля","sex":2,"online":1},{"id":22441902,"first_name":"Максим","last_name":"Чакир","sex":2,"bdate":"4.1.1994","city":{"id":1710959,"title":"Кишинев"},"online":1},{"id":23260033,"first_name":"Катя","last_name":"Кузьмина","sex":1,"bdate":"27.6.1994","city":{"id":1710959,"title":"Кишинев"},"online":0},{"id":24891252,"first_name":"Арина","last_name":"Горобец","sex":1,"bdate":"20.12.1994","city":{"id":1710959,"title":"Кишинев"},"online":1},{"id":33387222,"first_name":"Алёна","last_name":"Миколюк","sex":1,"bdate":"14.10","city":{"id":292,"title":"Одесса"},"online":1},{"id":38467274,"first_name":"Андрей","last_name":"Тросиненко","sex":2,"bdate":"19.3","online":0},{"id":38733273,"first_name":"Миха","last_name":"Романчук","sex":1,"bdate":"2.6.1937","city":{"id":1710959,"title":"Кишинев"},"online":0},{"id":39117080,"first_name":"Рома","last_name":"Беженарь","sex":2,"bdate":"14.10","city":{"id":1710959,"title":"Кишинев"},"online":1},{"id":45171519,"first_name":"Александр","last_name":"Огурцов","sex":2,"bdate":"22.6.1994","city":{"id":1710959,"title":"Кишинев"},"online":0},{"id":47147705,"first_name":"Никита","last_name":"Драгуцану","sex":2,"bdate":"28.12","city":{"id":1710959,"title":"Кишинев"},"online":0},{"id":58606740,"first_name":"Франческа","last_name":"Канна","sex":1,"bdate":"25.1","city":{"id":1710959,"title":"Кишинев"},"online":0},{"id":62678153,"first_name":"Лёша","last_name":"Кугут","sex":2,"city":{"id":1710959,"title":"Кишинев"},"online":0},{"id":67485434,"first_name":"Ирина","last_name":"Трапезникова","sex":1,"bdate":"15.7","city":{"id":1710959,"title":"Кишинев"},"online":1},{"id":76249958,"first_name":"Никита","last_name":"Литвинов","sex":2,"online":1},{"id":78574119,"first_name":"Женя","last_name":"Чередниченко","sex":2,"city":{"id":1710959,"title":"Кишинев"},"online":0},{"id":87816032,"first_name":"Саша","last_name":"Сергунин","sex":2,"bdate":"28.5.1994","city":{"id":1710959,"title":"Кишинев"},"online":0},{"id":91235673,"first_name":"Вадим","last_name":"Барский","sex":2,"bdate":"22.6.1994","city":{"id":1908479,"title":"Antananarivo"},"online":1},{"id":94373404,"first_name":"Никита","last_name":"Головко","sex":2,"bdate":"29.1","city":{"id":1710959,"title":"Кишинев"},"online":1},{"id":101047911,"first_name":"Алексей","last_name":"Кицак","sex":2,"bdate":"12.5","city":{"id":1710959,"title":"Кишинев"},"online":1},{"id":101208573,"first_name":"Глеб","last_name":"Глинянов","deactivated":"deleted","sex":2,"online":0},{"id":108330289,"first_name":"Саша","last_name":"Руденко","sex":2,"bdate":"16.6","online":0},{"id":129188949,"first_name":"Роман","last_name":"Бугаян","sex":2,"city":{"id":1710959,"title":"Кишинев"},"online":0},{"id":139584680,"first_name":"Кристиан","last_name":"Мбала","sex":2,"bdate":"10.6","city":{"id":1710959,"title":"Кишинев"},"online":0},{"id":154083054,"first_name":"Оля","last_name":"За
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
JSONObject o = new JSONObject(response.toString());
```

Should be this:

```
JSONObject o = new JSONObject(response.responseString);
```

Because you're trying to convert an object to string. And it's `toString` method will return `com.vk.sdk.api.VKResponse@42b40ac0` which is not json.

**EDIT**
Simply putting things:

Your JSON is one object. So you can start by parsing it like: `JSONObject o = new JSONObject(response.toString());`. If you want to get all the friends you need to iterate an array that's inside it.

For that you can do:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = o.getJSONArray("items"); //the array is "items" not response.
 for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) { //simple iteration
      JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i); //this contains 1 item
      Friend fr = new Friend();
      fr.setFirst_name(jsonObject.getString("first_name"));
      fr.setLast_name(jsonObject.getString("last_name"));
      fr.setSex(jsonObject.getString("sex")); //sex is an integer so you might want to change this
      //fr.setBdate(jsonObject.getString("bdate"));//there is no such field "bdate" on this json
      fr.setCity(jsonObject.getJSONObject("city").getString("title")); //city is an object. Not a string
      friendArrayList.add(fr);
 }
```

This is simple JSON parsing and you should be able to do it by youself. You have any trouble understanding the structure behind you might want to start reading some tutorials. This one is a good place to start: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/android-json-tutorial-create-and-parse-json-data.html

Comment: Thanks very much!!!But another error occured  Error parsing dataorg.json.JSONException: Value {"count":40,"items":[{"last_name":"Канна","id":10543136,"first_name":"Филип","sex":2,"online":0,"city":{"id":1710959,"title":"Кишинев"}},

Comment: BEcause that's not an array and you're trying to parse it as an array.

Comment: @VdovinN If the answer helped you, give at least an upvote. Because that is another issue you are having.

Comment: Pedro Oliveira, can you show a plan of action?After your post I ran out of ideas what to do next:)

Comment: Edited the answer. This is pretty straight forward json parse shenanigans. If you don't understand JSON at all you should start reading something.